# want to show the balloon

Tags: android

I am working on the map view and i want to show the balloon by clicking on the user which are displayed on the map view. i have done till it shows the use name and status using the dialog box.but i want the profile name, status, and button on small rectangle above the clicked balloon(balloon is the users on the map).please give me some idea to do so.
thank you.

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement your own overlays. Here is the standard way with an icon: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

And here is an example for a custom overlay: http://labs.emich.be/2009/12/06/how-to-make-a-custom-overlay-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)?